# Upper bound estimate $ab^3\leq c(a^2+b^2)^2$. Find optimal, or good, constants $c$

Tags: inequality, optimization, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to find a good upper bound estimate for the expression $ab^3$, where $a,b\in\mathbb R$, and it should be of the form $ab^3\leq c (a^2+b^2)^2, c\in\mathbb R.$

(The reason for the latter is, because in my application of this, $a^2+b^2$ is a physical quantity. So I would like to express the estimate in terms of it.)

By trial and error experiments with Maple, I found that $c=1/3$ yields quite a good estimate. But when I try to derive an estimate analytically, the best I got so far was $c=1/2$, since $ab\leq\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)$ gives

$$b^2\leq a^2+b^2\implies ab^3=(ab)b^2\leq\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)^2.$$

How can I either get the better $c=1/3$ estimate analytically, or prove it? (Or an even better one would do as well of course.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $b=ka$ for some $k\in\Bbb R$. Then $$\frac{ab^3}{(a^2+b^2)^2}=\frac{k^3a^4}{(a^2+k^2a^2)^2}=\frac{k^3}{(1+k^2)^2}=\frac1{k^{-3}+2k^{-1}+k}$$ which attains its maximum when the denominator is minimised (derivative is zero). Thus $$-\frac3{k^4}-\frac2{k^2}+1=0\implies(k^2+1)(k^2-3)=0\implies k=\pm\sqrt3$$ so $c=\dfrac{3\sqrt3}{16}$.

Comment: The constant is about $0.32476$, so OP's $ \frac 13$ is quite close.  I was just doing the same.

Comment: I had started with Lagrange multipliers, but this is far simpler.

Comment: And what is in the case $$b=\sqrt{k}a$$?

Comment: @MartinR Lagrange was my first thought, but then I realised that there wasn't a finite constraint on $a,b$

Comment: Very elegant! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, this trick is sometimes very useful when you can spot some variable eliminations.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Do you really think that your solution is elegant? Actually. If you'll see down-voting for your solution, it's not mine.

Answer (score 2):

*Another way*: As this is homogeneous, we may set $a^2+b^2=1$, whence it is maximising $\sin t \cos^3t$, which is easy to see happens when say $t=\pi/6$.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM
$$(a^2+b^2)^2=\left(a^2+3\cdot\frac{b^2}{3}\right)^2\geq\left(4\sqrt[4]{a^2\left(\frac{b^2}{3}\right)^3}\right)^2=\frac{16}{3\sqrt3}|ab^3|\geq\frac{16}{3\sqrt3}ab^3.$$
The equality occurs for $a=\frac{b}{\sqrt3},$ which says that $c=\frac{3\sqrt3}{16}.$